# UI for multiplatform .net Application

Tags: user-interface, multiplatform

I want to get my programme running on Linux but I don't kow what to do about the UI. Right now I'm using WPF but it probably won't be supported by Mono too soon. The UI controls are edited directly by the non-UI code.

Switching to Windows Forms would be easiest but I think it doesn't really look good on Linux.

What I am dreaming of right now is having some kind of abstract UI that provides the standard controls (with the standard members) and keeps the non-UI code away from the rest. So I would have to translate changes in the abstract UI to the concrete UI. This would be a lot of work but the code would be highly re-usable.

What would you do and what do you think of the last idea?

(It would be good if it would not require anything new to be installed on Windows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use Wrapper classes that implement interfaces like IButton.

If it works in the long term I'll upload the code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've not worked with that myself, but you could take a look at [wx.NET](http://wxnet.sourceforge.net/) which is a .net wrapper for [wxWidget](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) (I have used the latter for cross-platform UI design and quite liked them :-).

Answer (score 0):

One simple suggestion might be [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp)

Comment: I'd prefer it if it would run on Windows without having to install something else.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used Gtk#, but it is really *ugly* in Windows applications, you could use Windows Forms 2.0 in the last release of Mono. Or you could even use Trolltech's Qt 4 with .net using this http://code.google.com/p/qt4dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like [Eto.Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto), which is a .NET library that allows you to write a single common UI, which is then translated to the native toolkit using WinForms, GTK#, or MonoMac/Cocoa.

The benefit to using this approach is your app will look native on every platform.

There are also WPF and iOS ports in the works, which you will be able to switch to when they are ready.

Comment: WPF is now fully implemented!